# Why should I include return here?

Tags: javascript, return

I understand part of how it works `return;`
but this situation I don't understand.
If I delete the `return obj` then, it cause error..
Why should I include the `return obj`??

```
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car',
      'truck'
    ];

    const sumUp = data.reduce(function (obj, item) {
      if (!obj[item]) {
        obj[item] = 0; 
      }
      obj[item]++;
      return obj;
    }, {});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'car' of undefined

Comment: in first iteration, `obj` is `{}`, i.e. an empty object. In second and further iterations, `obj` is what you return - if you don't return anything, `obj` will be `undefined` and cause errors when you try to add properties to it

Comment: Do you understand how `reduce` works?

Comment: The only real answer is that "because that's how `reduce` works". The whole point of it is that the return value from one invocation is passed to the subsequent invocation. If you don't `return` anything, then by definition the next iteration will not receive anything (or more specifically, it will receive `undefined`).

Answer (score 2):

The reduce callback requires a return that reduce continues to use. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters) for a more in-depth explanaton for how the reduce function works and how the callback is used.

Here is a simple example of how to use reduce to return the sum of numbers in an array.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(accum, val) {
  return accum + val;
}, 0);

// Outputs 10
```

Essentially, your callback is invoked with the current accumulator, the current value, current index in the beginning array, and the array being used.

Each time your callback is used, reduce expects your callback to modify the accumulator in some way, like add the next number in my above example, and return it for reduce to pass to your callback again or return as the final result.